# How to globally get an HTML element once and use it multiple times?

Tags: javascript

I don't want to invoke

```
        var element = document.getElementById('ph');
```

every time the `UpdateClock` get called for the sake of efficiency. So I attempted to put it globally rather than putting it inside `UpdateClock`. However, it does not work.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>This is a title</title>
    <script>
        var element = document.getElementById('ph');

        function UpdateClock() {
            var now = new Date();
            var hours = now.getHours();
            var minutes = now.getMinutes();
            var seconds = now.getSeconds();

            if (hours < 10)
                hours = "0" + hours;
            if (minutes < 10)
                minutes = "0" + minutes;
            if (seconds < 10)
                seconds = "0" + seconds;
            element.innerHTML = hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds;
        }

    </script>

</head>
<body onload="setInterval('UpdateClock()', 1000)">
    <h1 id="ph"></h1>
</body>
</html>
```

What is wrong? Is there anything I am missing here?

Comment: Note that I am new to `javascript`. This code is my first code with JS.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to run the code that does the assignment *after* you have added the element to the DOM.

The simplest way is:

```
<h1 id="ph"></h1>
<script>
    var element = document.getElementById('ph');
</script>
```

Alternatively, use an event handler that runs after the element is added.

```
<script>
    var element;
    addEventListener('load', function () {
        element = document.getElementById('ph');
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

Edited: I initially misunderstood the question.

Put the script tags inside the body, at the bottom

```
<script>
....js here
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: Please explain in more details as I don't understand it.

Comment: It's not wrapped in a function, so the use of `var` doesn't prevent it being in the global scope.